# i am using mail() in php . when i change the subject of my mail , mails are going to spam. how to avoid it when i change the subject line

Tags: php, email

i have used `mail()` , when i tried with "test" as subject mails are going fine to the inbox but when i change the subject line to 6 or 7 words mails are going to spam . Please can any one help me out . because my subject will be keep on changing so i need a permanent solution even after i change the subject line .

i have tried to put the sender in $header and i checked with mime type still it does not work

```
require_once("mailer.php");

    if(isset($_POST['to']) && !empty($_POST['to']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['from']) 
    && !empty($_POST['from'])){
    $receieverEmailIdArray = explode(',',$_POST['to']);
    $from= $_POST['from'];

    $subject= $_POST['subject'];
    }

    else {
        echo "Fill all the fields.";
        die();
    }

    $smtptype= 'godaddy';

    $content= "<html>
</html>"
```

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: This code doesn't even send e-mails at all, wheres the actual code?

Comment: Also, don't use `mail()`, it a too basic e-mailing implementation and its full of issues, try the PEAR Mail class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Detailed headers Code below.

```
$headers = "From: Example@site.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Example@site.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: Example@site.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: Example@site.com\r\n";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) 
  {
 echo "The email has been Successfully sent!";
  } 
 else
  {
  echo "Email Sending Failed";
   }
  ?>
```

Refer this Site this has some useful Information [Click Here!!!](http://www.transio.com/content/how-pass-spam-filters-php-mail)

Comment: You need to add `\r\n` to each header line